# Android - Retrofit2 Authorization with Bearer Token stored in SharedPreferences

Tags: android, kotlin, authentication, sharedpreferences, retrofit2

I'm trying to use Retrofit2 in Android app, I'd like to add Bearer Token to http request header which stored with SharedPreferences.
But the below code return the error when launch app.

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference

```
object RetrofitInstance : Application() {
    private const val API_BASE_URL = BuildConfig.API_BASE_URL

    private val sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences by lazy {
        applicationContext.getSharedPreferences(
            applicationContext.getString(R.string.preference_file_key),
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE
        )
    }

    private val httpBuilder: OkHttpClient.Builder
        get() {
            val httpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .addInterceptor(Interceptor { chain ->
                    val original = chain.request()
                    
                    val bearerToken = sharedPreferences.getString(
                        applicationContext.getString(R.string.preference_token_data_key),
                        null
                    )

                    val request = original.newBuilder()
                        .header("Accept", "application/json")
                        .header("Authorization", "Bearer $bearerToken")
                        .build()

                    return@Interceptor chain.proceed(request)
                })

            return httpClient
        }

    private val retrofit by lazy {
        Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(API_BASE_URL)
            .client(httpBuilder.build())
            .addConverterFactory(
                MoshiConverterFactory.create(
                    Moshi.Builder().add(KotlinJsonAdapterFactory()).build()
                )
            )
            .addCallAdapterFactory(ResultCallAdapterFactory())
            .build()
    }

    val api: TestService by lazy {
        retrofit.create(TestService::class.java)
    }

}
```

Is there any way to use the value stored with SharedPreferences in Singleton Object?

Answer (score 0):

The Application class in your Android App is Singleton; what you need to do is change the `object` to `class`, add this class to the AndroidManifest.xml
like that `android:name=".RetrofitInstance"`, and then get access to that class in your activities or fragments like the following

```kotlin
(application as RetrofitInstance).api
```

But I don't think this is the right place for such a thing, usually we create separate files that handle the creation and configuration for retrofit, a separate class that wraps the `SharedPreferences,` and have another implementation entity that integrates these two (get the data from shared preferences and pass them to the Retrofit OkHttpBuilder).